# Stack data into rows with two headers and first header is not merged

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have xlsx data like below.

```
      Q1 Q1 Q1 Q2 Q2 Q2
      V1 V2 V3 V1 V2 V3 
 Ram  11 19 10 10 12 14 
 Syam 11 19 10 10 12 14
```

I have to convert it to below format.

```
        V1 V2 V3
 Ram Q1 11 19 10
Syam Q1 11 19 10
 Ram Q2 10 12 14
Syam Q2 10 12 14
```

I don't have access to change the source format.
i have tried like below.

```
df=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name='Sheet1',header=[0,1],index=[0,1])

df.stack(level=0)
```

But it is not working as the first row cells are not in merged format. looking for any pandas functions to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `index_col=0` when reading in the data. Then, perform the operations: `.stack(0)` and `reset_index()`. Passing the `0` in `.stack(0)` ensures you put the `V`s on columns and `Q`s on rows, versus vice versa with `stack(1)`, since you have a multi-index of two rows in your columns:

```
df = (pd.read_excel('Desktop\Book1.xlsx',header=[0,1], index_col=0).stack(0).reset_index()
        .rename({'level_0' : '', 'level_1' : ''}, axis=1))
df
Out[1]: 
             V1  V2  V3
0   Ram  Q1  11  19  10
1   Ram  Q2  10  12  14
2  Syam  Q1  11  19  10
3  Syam  Q2  10  12  14
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow !

Here's how far I got towards finding a solution for this.

First, data should be read such as to have `Ram` and `Syam` as index column:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name='Sheet1',header=[0,1],index_col=0)
```

Then, the method that you want is `stack` ([reshaping guide](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/reshaping.html))

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
       Q1          Q2
       V1  V2  V3  V1  V2  V3
 Ram   11  19  10  10  12  14
 Syam  11  19  10  10  12  14

In [53]: df.stack()
Out[53]:
              Q1   Q2

 Ram   V1     11   10
       V2     19   12
       V3     10   14
 Syam  V1     11   10
       V2     19   12
       V3     10   14
```

Hoever, without any arguments,it stacks the last level of the columns, which, as we can see, is the one of `V`. We want to stack the first level, so need to call `df.stack(0)`.

However, when doing so, an error arises: `ValueError: The name       occurs multiple times, use a level number`. To me, this looks like a bug on `pandas` side.

**Edit:**
After some investigation, I realised that the levels of my `df` had the same name:

```
In [75]: df.columns
Out[75]:
MultiIndex([(' Q1', ' V1'),
            (' Q1', ' V2'),
            (' Q1', ' V3'),
            (' Q2', ' V1'),
            (' Q2', ' V2'),
            (' Q2', ' V3')],
           names=['     ', '     '])
```

consisting of      (4 spaces).

If, instead, we make sure that the levels have different names:

```
In [89]: df.columns.names = ['H1', 'H2']

In [90]: df
Out[90]:
H1    Q1          Q2
H2    V1  V2  V3  V1  V2  V3
Ram   11  19  10  10  12  14
Syam  11  19  10  10  12  14
```

then we can correctly apply `df.stack(0)`:

```
In [91]: df.stack(0)
Out[91]:
H2         V1   V2   V3
      H1
Ram   Q1   11   19   10
      Q2   10   12   14
Syam  Q1   11   19   10
      Q2   10   12   14
```